# Postgres query to list all folksonomy-tags for items that match certain tags

Tags: postgresql, left-join, folksonomy

I'm working on a Postgres database storing taggable items; it uses the typical stricture for this (table for items with an item_id, table for tags with a tag_id and a tag_name, table of each instance where a given item has a given tag). I've assembled this query which almost does what I want, to retrieve items matching at least one of the chosen tags and display all info about the item:

```
SELECT items.item_id, items.item_name, items.item_description,
    ARRAY_AGG(tags.tag_name) AS tag_name_list
FROM items
LEFT JOIN item_tags ON items.item_id = item_tags.item_id
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.tag_id = item_tags.tag_id
WHERE tags.tag_name  IN ('one','two') 
GROUP BY items.item_id;
```

The problem is that the part which lists the item's tags will only list the matching ones, not all of them. (For example, if something has tags one, two, and three, this specific query will suggest that it only has one and two.)

I suppose I could to this with nested SELECT statements, but this feels more correct, and I haven't yet figured out how to do it that way anyway.

EDIT: Per suggestion, I've modified it to this but I get the exact same result.

```
SELECT items.item_id, items.item_name, items.item_description,
    ARRAY_AGG(tags.tag_name) AS tag_name_list
FROM items
LEFT JOIN item_tags ON items.item_id = item_tags.item_id
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.tag_id = item_tags.tag_id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tags
    WHERE tags.tag_name IN ('two','three')
    AND tags.tag_id = item_tags.tag_id
) 
GROUP BY items.item_id;
```

EDIT 2: So I settled for a subquery approach:

```
SELECT items.item_id, items.item_name, items.item_description,
    ARRAY_AGG(tag_name) AS tag_name_list
FROM item_tags, tags, items

WHERE item_tags.item_id IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT item_id FROM item_tags WHERE tag_id IN
    (
        SELECT tag_id FROM tags WHERE tag_name  IN ('one','two')
    )
)
AND tags.tag_id = item_tags.tag_id
AND items.item_id = item_tags.item_id

GROUP BY items.item_id;
```

Comment: Hint: use `exists(...)` in the where-clause.

Comment: That seems helpful, but I'm still stuck... (see appended edit)

Comment: You need to join item_tags separately in the exists() part. (also: you dont want a LEFT join) Also: you might need to add some aliases.

Comment: Since you finally found something that works, I posted my answer.

Comment: I think yours will work just as well (but you *should* use the JOIN-syntax, IMHO) In my version, the `JOIN ... ON EXISTS(...)` is kind of kinky, but it keeps the bridge table out of the outer rangetable.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i.item_id, i.item_name, i.item_description,
    ARRAY_AGG(t.tag_name) AS tag_name_list
FROM items i
JOIN tags t ON EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM item_tags it
        WHERE i.item_id = it.item_id
        AND t.tag_id = it.tag_id
        )
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM item_tags xit
        JOIN tags t ON t.tag_id = xit.tag_id
        WHERE xit.item_id = i.item_id
        AND t.tag_name  IN ('one','two')
        )
GROUP BY i.item_id;
```